# How do I only get part of the users input and discard the other characters when using "fgets"?

Tags: c

I am a C beginner. I noticed something weird about the Maximum number of characters to be copied into str when using fgets. The part of the code is as follow:

```
char reply[10];


printf("Your reply is ->");
fgets(reply,2,stdin);

if(0)
{
    REPLY:
    printf("Please reply again ->");
    fgets(reply,2,stdin);
}

printf("\nreply = %s\n",reply);

if(strncmp(reply,"Y",2) == 0)
{
    printf("\nCOOL!! Now let's start the game. Have fun!!!\n");
    memset(reply, 0, sizeof(reply));
}
else if(strncmp(reply,"N",2) == 0)
{
    printf("\nPlease read through the instruction again.\n");
    memset(reply, 0, sizeof(reply));
}
else
{
    printf("\nInvalid response\n");
    memset(reply, 0, sizeof(reply));
    goto REPLY;
}
```

The user inputs something like "asdwq", which is an invalid response as in my code said. Then, the output becomes weird and could someone explain the output below to me?

```
 Your reply is ->asdwq

 reply = a

 Invalid response
 Please reply again ->
 reply = s

 Invalid response
 Please reply again ->
 reply = d

 Invalid response
 Please reply again ->
 reply = w

 Invalid response
 Please reply again ->
 reply = q

 Invalid response
 Please reply again ->
 reply =


 Invalid response
 Please reply again ->
```

So, my question is why would it still have the rest of the input even if I stated the maximum number of "2" in the fgets function. The loop cycles several times. It seems like the whole user's input is still stored "somewhere" in the computer. What's the explanation behind it and how do I only get part of the input and discard the others?

Comment: It is: in an input buffer. The rest is not discarded but read next time.

Comment: Two is a very restrictive limit for `fgets`, which guarantees to null-terminate the string. That means that there is room for only one character and your input "asdwq" will be consumed by 6 subsequent calls to `fgets` -- five for the letters and one for the new-line character. A fix is to read a longer line of maybe 80 chars and then `sscanf` to get the first word.

Comment: @MOehm, I think 2 is the sample value used just to show something that doesn't force you to enter many characters to see the buffer limit in `fgets(3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fgets(reply,2,stdin);
```

reads in a single character at most plus 1 for the terminating null character that [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) stores at `reply[1]` (assuming no input failures). Once user enters an invalid input, the rest of the input left in the input stream is consumed by the subsequent `fgets()` calls. So you have to *remove* them.

One way to do is using `getchar()` in a loop:

```
while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n');
```

I have say your input reading is unusual and unreadable. You need to learn about using loops e.g., using `fgets() in a`do-while` loop.

I'd also suggest you check return value of `fgets()` (returns NULL on failure) too.